# 3D Stereo - Saving both Left and Right render images

Tags: rendering, stereoscopy

I wrote this code to save the render buffer:

```
bpy.ops.render.render(scene="Scene")
bpy.data.images['Render Result'].save_render('D:\\render.png')
```

But it doesn't work if I have a stereo camera.

Generally, if I click on *Image > Save As Image* Blender saves both the images adding _L and _R suffix to the filename if the Stereo 3D is enabled.

Some suggest on how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the render result you can simply use the keyword argument [`write_still = True`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.ops.render.html?#bpy.ops.render.render).

The saved image will conform to your view format settings in the render options panel. If you set the view format to *Individual*, the following lines will save two images named `render_L.png` and `render_R.png`.

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = 'D:\\render.png'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: It works. 
Actually I prefer to use filenames different from the one blender use to save the rendered files....but I could use it as a temporary solution.
Thanks for the suggest binweg!

Comment: The suffix is defined in Render Layers > Views > File Suffix, you can edit that... @Give_me_back_Softimage_bastard